# jQuery fade out div on hover. Links not selectable

Tags: jquery, css

I Am using jquery to fade a div on hover, But the anchor link cant be selected once shown.

```
$('#show').hover(function() {
    $(this).stop(true).fadeTo("slow", 0);
}, function() {
    $(this).stop(true).fadeTo("slow", 1);
});
```

It looks like the div that gets faded is still actually on top of the hidden div.

example : http://jsfiddle.net/BJwn7/81/

How can I make the link selectable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using jquery fade just changes the opacity of the element

So the img thats overlayed is still on top of the link but its opacity is just 0.

After the fade you need to hide the the div which will set its style to `display: none`

```
$('#container').hover(function() {
    $('#show').stop(true).fadeTo("slow", 0, function() { $(this).hide(); });
}, function() {
    $('#show').stop(true).fadeTo("slow", 1, function () { $(this).show(); });
});
```

Here is a jsfilddle
http://jsfiddle.net/ddvcJ/

Comment: Yes, here is it sort of working w/ class'.  http://jsfiddle.net/McfZJ/

this will need some more work. I would recommend taking out the javascript and setting the img to display: none and then figuring out how to make the link clickable. through css.  Use css to setup your end states.. then use jquery to transition between states.

Comment: I modified the code a little to work if there are more than one image. A little buggy but it works for me on my site. example http://jsfiddle.net/ddvcJ/3/

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the jQuery to this:

```
$('#container').hover(function() {
    $('#show').fadeOut("slow");
}, function() {
    $('#show').fadeIn("slow");
});
```

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BJwn7/86/

Comment: it doesn't change to old state when hover out

Answer (score 1):

Changed some css and jquery codes check out this **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BJwn7/83/)**

```
<div id="container" style="position: relative">
    <img id="show" src="http://img14.imageshack.us/img14/9698/29588166.jpg" alt="" height="300px"/>
    <div id="hidden"><a href="#">link</a></div>
</div>


#container {
    width: 166px;
}
#hidden {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 300px;
    width: 166px;
    background: red;
    display:none;
}

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#container").hover(function(){
    $("#hidden").fadeToggle("fast");
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

1. I'd better put image down the `div`
2. assign different events both to `div` and `img`

   ```
   $('#show').mouseenter(function() {
       $(this).stop(true).fadeOut("slow");
   });
   $('#hidden').mouseleave(function() {
       $('#show').stop(true).fadeIn("slow");
   });
   ```

**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vladkras/FTxzj/)**

Comment: If you move the mouse over the div a few times quickly it gets stuck